# How to prevent losing the Max-Age portion of my Cache-Control header in AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, cache-control, appharbor

I have an ASP.NET / MVC web app which when running locally produces this header:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=3
Connection:Close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:287122
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Thu, 26 Jul 2012 21:21:26 GMT
ETag:K5fBpkMM+t9XPl07ydQ54pR6bg8=
Expires:Thu, 26 Jul 2012 21:21:29 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
```

But when running in AppHarbor behind their proxy the headers I get are these:

```
Cache-Control:public
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:287122
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Thu, 26 Jul 2012 21:22:49 GMT
ETag:K5fBpkMM+t9XPl07ydQ54pR6bg8=
Expires:Thu, 26 Jul 2012 21:22:41 GMT
Server:nginx
```

AppHarbor is stripping the Max-Age portion of my Cache-Control header and stomping over my Date with one I'm not synchronized with.

My goal is serve JavaScript via a CDN with a very short max age so that changes can be rolled out quickly. Changing the url frequently is not an option.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you plan to run your CDN off AppHarbor?

Comment: 3 seconds seems a rather short time to be caching - in fact it stretches the definition of the word "cache" somewhat. Won't the CDN servers be constantly hitting your server for an update? What about adding a version querystring to the script reference in the page to control the caching behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

A college who more closely examined the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) noticed that it looks like the common one line form of this header used by servers and browsers:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=X
```

isn't actually valid. Splitting the two parts of the header into two lines like so:

```
Cache-Control: public
Cache-Control: max-age=X
```

works! So in my .net code, this:

```
response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
response.Cache.SetMaxAge(MaxAge);
```

becomes this:

```
response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (int)MaxAge.TotalSeconds);
```

and now I can get a max-age out of AppHarbor.